# Google Apps Script calling MVC Controller not Serializing Correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, google-apps-script

I'm writing a Google Apps Script that is taking data from a Google Sheet, and sending to an ASP.NET MVC controller action. The call to MVC is never serializing correctly, and it's failing as a null reference.

Google Apps Script :

```js
function exportPlayers()
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("RF 2015 Working Roster");
  var rows = sheet.getRange("C3:H").getValues();
  var players = [];

  for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++)
  {
    var row = rows[i];
    if(row[0] != "" && row[1] != "")
    {
      Logger.log('row ' + row);

      var playerId = "" + parseInt(i + 1) + "";
      var teamId = "" + row[0] + "";
      var player =
          {
            "PartitionKey" : teamId,
            "RowKey": playerId,
            "PlayerId" : playerId,
            "TeamId" : teamId,
            "FirstName" : row[1], 
            "LastName" : row[2], 
            "TeamName": row[5]
          };  

        players.push(player);       
    }       
  }

  var options =
      {
        "method" : "post",
        "payload" : JSON.stringify({ players : players  }) 
      };

  UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://{My URL}/player/save", options);    

}
```

My C# MVC Controller Action:

```c#
public void Save(List<Player> players)
{
    ScheduleCalculator calculator = new ScheduleCalculator();
    calculator.SavePlayers(players);
}

[Serializable]
    public class Player : TableEntity
    {
        public int PlayerId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string TeamName { get; set; }
        public int TeamId { get; set; }
        public PlayerType Type { get; set; }
    }

    public enum PlayerType
    {
        PaidMember,
        Sub
    }
```

The `calculator.SavePlayers(players);` call is failing because `players` is null. I can not figure out how to structure the Google Apps Script so it serializes correctly.

Comment: What if your payload is changed to `JSON.stringify(players)`?

Answer (score 0):

You're passing it an object with a field called `players`. The api method is expecting an array of players.

What you're sending:

```
{players: [{...}, {...}, ...]}
```

What the API expects:

```
[{...}, {...}, ...]
```

To fix this, change this:

```
var options = {"method" : "post",
               "payload" : JSON.stringify({ players : players  })};
```

to

```
var options ={"method" : "post",
              "payload" : JSON.stringify(players)};
```

EDIT: Based on the addition of the player class, here are a few more things I can see:

The following line:

```
var playerId = "" + parseInt(i + 1) + "";
```

creates a string. The class expects an integer. Remove the double quotes (and you can also remove the `parseInt`, since you're adding two integers together):

```
var playerId = i + 1;
```

The `teamId` has the same problem, but it's also getting the value from the google sheet, so I'm not sure whether it will receive an `int` or not. To be sure, remove the quotes and make sure it's an `int`:

```
var teamId = parseInt(row[0]);
```

Comment: Same error:

Exception message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Could you show us the `Player`-class in c#? It would also help if you could show us what gets sent over the wire (you can use Fiddler or the WebDev tools in your browsers for that).

Comment: Added Player object into the main message.  I really don't know the best way to capture the request, because it's a google app script it's being ran on google servers.  I'll play with it and see if there is way to log that...Thanks Again Kenneth!

Comment: Added some more things to check

Comment: I got it.... Here is what i was missing:

  var options =
      {
        "method" : "post",
        "contentType": "application/json",
        "payload" : JSON.stringify(players) 
      };

It had to have that contentType on it i guess...  Thank you for all your help Kenneth :)

Comment: Yes, indeed, otherwise Web API doesn't know what serializer to use.

Answer (score 0):

```
            var options = 
            { 
                "method" : "post", 
                "contentType": "application/json", 
                "payload" : JSON.stringify(players) 
            };
```

Specifying the "ContentType": "application/json" in the options fixed the issue why the payload wasn't being interpreted properly on the service layer.  As Kenneth said in comments, the "ContentType" let's the Service Endpoint know how to deal with the message properly.  Google scripts defaults to 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' or 'multipart/form-data'.